# Howto tell PowerBuilder to pass options to a JVM when starting?

Tags: jvm, powerbuilder

**What I want to do?**

I want to create and consume java objects in PowerBuilder and call methods on it. This should happen with less overhead possible.
I do not want to consume java webservices!

So I've a working sample in which I can create a java object, call a method on this object and output the result from the called method.
Everything is working as expected. I'm using Java 1.8.0_31.

But now I want to attach my java IDE (IntelliJ) to the running JVM (started by PowerBuilder) to debug the java code which gets called by PowerBuilder.

**And now my question**.

How do I tell PowerBuilder to add special options when starting the JVM?
In special I want to add the following option(s) in some way:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

The JVM is created like following:

```
LONG ll_result
inv_java = CREATE JavaVM

ll_result = inv_java.CreateJavaVM("C:\Development\tms java\pbJavaTest", FALSE)
CHOOSE CASE ll_result
    CASE 1
    CASE 0
    CASE -1
        MessageBox ( "", "jvm.dll was not found in the classpath.")
    CASE -2
        MessageBox ( "", "pbejbclient90.jar file was not found." )
    CASE ELSE
        MessageBox ( "", "Unknown result (" + String (ll_result ) +")"  )
END CHOOSE
```

In the PowerBuilder help I found something about overriding the static registry classpath. There is something written about custom properties which sounds like what I'm looking for.
But there's no example on how to add JVM options to override default behavior.

Does anyone have a clue on how to tell PowerBuilder to use my options? 
Or does anyone have any advice which could guide me in the right direction?

**Update 1**

I found an old post which solved my initial issue.
If someone else want to know how it works take a look at this post:
http://nntp-archive.sybase.com/nntp-archive/action/article/%3C46262213.6742.1681692777@sybase.com%3E

> Hi, you need to set some windows registry entries.
>
> Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Sybase\Powerbuilder\9.0\Java, there
>   are two folders: PBIDEConfig and PBRTConfig. The first one is used when
>   you run your application from within the IDE, and the latter is used
>   when you run your compiled application. Those two folders can have
>   PBJVMconfig and PBJVMprops folders within them.
>
> PBJVMconfig is for JVM configuration options such as -Xms. You have to
>   specify incremental key values starting from "0" by one, and one special
>   key "Count" to tell Powerbuilder how many options exists to enumerate.
>
> PBJVMprops is for all -D options. You do not need to specify -D for
>   PBJVMProps, just the name of the property and its value, and as many
>   properties as you wish.
>
> Let me give some examples:
>
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Sybase\PowerBuilder\9.0\Java\PBIDEConfig\PBJVMprops]
>   "java.security.auth.login.config"="auth.conf"
>   "user.language"="en"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Sybase\PowerBuilder\9.0\Java\PBRTConfig\PBJVMconfig]
>   "0"="-client"
>   "1"="-Xms128m"
>   "2"="-Xmx512m"
>   "Count"="3"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Sybase\PowerBuilder\9.0\Java\PBRTConfig\PBJVMprops]
>   "java.security.auth.login.config"="auth.conf"
>   "user.language"="en"
>
> Regards,
>   Gokhan Demir

But now there's another issue...
PB isn't able to create EJB Proxies for my sample class which is really simple with java 1.8.0_31. They were created with the default version, which is 1.6.0_24.

```
public class Simple
{
  public Simple()
  {
  }

  public static String getValue()
  {
    return "blubber";
  }

  public int getInt32Value()
  {
    return 123456;
  }

  public double getDoubleVaue()
  {
    return 123.123;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(Simple.getValue());
  }
}
```

The error is the following. :D

```
 ---------- Deploy: Deploy of project p_genapp_ejbclientproxy   (15:35:18)
Retrieving PowerBuilder Proxies from EJB...
    Generation Errors:  Error: class not found: ( 
    Deployment Error:   No files returned for package/component 'Simple'.       Error code: Unknown.   Proxy was not created.
Done.
 ---------- Finished Deploy of project p_genapp_ejbclientproxy   (15:35:19)
```

So the whole way isn't a option because we do not want to change the JAVA settings in PB back and forth just to generate new EJB Proxies for changed JAVA objects in the future...

So one option to test will be creating COM wrappers for JAVA classes to use them in PB...

Comment: Review the following information, it could be a solution: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-set-java-properties-system-wide.html

Comment: Thx for your reply. But setting global options to all JVM's isn't a way I want to go.